# How to get jsonObject in jsonArray complex

Tags: android

i want to ask i have some json response and why i cannot get value from jsonArray related_news

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "message": "OK",
    "query": {
        "related": "true",
        "is_admin": true
    },
    "data": {
        "title": "Jadwal Pertandingan dan Siaran Langsung Grup D Piala Presiden 2018, Senin 29 Januari",
        "news_type": "Liga",
        "sub_news_type": "Liga Indonesia",
        "credit": "",
        "meta_description": "Jadwal Pertandingan dan Siaran Langsung Grup D Piala Presiden 2018, Senin 29 Januari",
        "recommended": "1",
        "tag": "Piala Presiden",
        "slug": "jadwal-pertandingan-dan-siaran-langsung-grup-d-piala-presiden-2018-senin-29-januari",
        "createon": "28 January 2018 20:09:31",
        "updateon": null,
        "publish_on": "2018-01-28 21:50:43",
        "news_like": 15,
        "news_smile": 0,
        "news_shock": 0,
        "news_inspired": 0,
        "news_happy": 0,
        "news_sad": 0,
        "news_fear": 0,
        "news_angry": 0,
        "news_fun": 0,
        "username": "bayu_m",
        "fullname": "Bayu Mahendra",
        "related_news": [
            {
                "title": "Bhayangkara FC Siapkan Taktik Sapu Jagat Lawan PSM",
                "slug": "bhayangkara-fc-siapkan-taktik-sapu-jagat-lawan-psm",
                "createon": "17 October 2017 14:47:56",
                "updateon": "",
                "publish_on": "2017-10-17 14:45:37",
                "news_view": 73
            }
     ]
    }
}
```

here my execution

```
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(s);
            String status = result.get("status").toString(),
            message=result.getString("message");
```

//                Log.d("log"," result : "+s);

```
            if(status.equals("Success")&& message.equals("OK")){
                Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this,"wellcome"+result.getJSONObject("data").getString("fullname"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                JSONObject data=result.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray arr=data.getJSONArray("related_news");
                String values=arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
                for(int chcek=0;chcek<data.length();chcek++){
                    Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this,"wellcome"+values,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            //                    Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this,"cxcxcx"+String.valueOf(data.getJSONArray("related_news").length()<0?"hmmm":"xxxxx"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

wrong in here 
not value in related_news can someone help me thanks

Comment: Please show the error

Comment: thanks for response no value in related_news

Comment: its because json object in `related_news` array does not have a name value pair with key `id`

Comment: String values=arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("id"); There is no tag for "id"

Comment: i change id to title but still cannot @AswinPAshok

Comment: is the toast working? And are you sure the `Log.d("log"," result : "+s);` logs the same data as you posted above?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @seropo I tried your same code with same JSON string, with `String values = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("title");` and tried logging `values`, And it works. So my guess is, you are not getting this data always. Before you do `String values = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("title");` try logging  `arr.length();` to make sure you are not getting an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `result.getString("status")` to get the Status as Status is a String("Success")

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject(s);
String status = result.getString("status");
String message=result.getString("message");
```

Check this code.

```
 JSONObject data=result.getJSONObject("data");
 JSONArray arr=data.getJSONArray("related_news");

for(int chcek=0;chcek<data.length();chcek++){
   Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this,"wellcome"+values,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
}
```

`data` is not `array`

Use this

```
JSONArray arr=data.getJSONArray("related_news");
for(int chcek=0;chcek<arr.length();chcek++){
  JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(check);
  String title  = object.getString("title");
  Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this,title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: thanks but thats not problem i cannot get object value in array related_news

Comment: JSONObject data=result.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray arr=data.getJSONArray("related_news");
                    for(int chcek=0;chcek<arr.length();chcek++){
                        JSONObject values=arr.getJSONObject(chcek);
                        String id=values.getString("id");
                        Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this,"wellcome"+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

Comment: i try that but still cannot

Comment: updated my answer. You can debug the code to see what its not working

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line-:

```
String values=arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
```

because id doesnt exist in related news array.Try the value that exists.

For eg-:

```
String values=arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("title");
```

Execution will fail and will not move further so remove that line.

Comment: still cannot i change id to title still says no value in related_news

Comment: Do this-:
String status = result.getString("status");
Change this too.

Comment: @pskink no value in related_news

Comment: @pskink No value for related_news thats from my log

Comment: @pskink D/log: exception -> No value for related_news only thats from my log thats all

Comment: @pskink app is  crash but i use try catch statement and result from catch is no value for related_news only thats i see and i use Log.d("log","exception ->"+e.getMessage().toString())

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
```

The key of `id` does not exist within the related news object, and the next line is a loop anyway, so not really necessary for you to have `getJSONObject(0)` unless the first element is special, or you're guaranteed to have it

In fact,  `id` is not present in any of the data you gave.

Please check your keys more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject(s);
String status = result.getString("status");
String message = result.getString("message");

        Log.i("log", " result : " + result);

        Log.i("Status ", ":" + status);
        Log.i("Message ", ":" + message);


        if (status.equals("Success") && message.equals("OK")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wellcome" + result.getJSONObject("data").getString("fullname"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String news_type = data.getString("news_type");
            String sub_news_type = data.getString("sub_news_type");
            String credit = data.getString("credit");
            String username = data.getString("username");
            String fullname = data.getString("fullname");

            Log.i("Data Title ", ":" + title);
            Log.i("Data news_type ", ":" + news_type);
            Log.i("Data sub_news_type ", ":" + sub_news_type);
            Log.i("Data credit ", ":" + credit);
            Log.i("Data username ", ":" + username);
            Log.i("Data fullname ", ":" + fullname);


            JSONArray arr = data.getJSONArray("related_news");

            for (int chcek = 0; chcek < arr.length(); chcek++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = arr.getJSONObject(chcek);

                String news_title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                String slug = jsonObject.getString("slug");
                String createon = jsonObject.getString("createon");
                String updateon = jsonObject.getString("updateon");
                String publish_on = jsonObject.getString("publish_on");
                String news_view = jsonObject.getString("news_view");

                Log.i("News Title ", ":" + news_title);
                Log.i("News slug ", ":" + slug);
                Log.i("News createon ", ":" + createon);
                Log.i("News updateon ", ":" + updateon);
                Log.i("News publish_on ", ":" + publish_on);
                Log.i("News news_view ", ":" + news_view);

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, title + "This is title value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @seropo please check my answer.

Comment: i try it but cannot resolve  JSONObject data=result.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray arr=data.getJSONArray("related_news");
                    for(int chcek=0;chcek<arr.length();chcek++){
                        JSONObject values=arr.getJSONObject(chcek);
                        String id=values.getString("id");
                        Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this,"wellcome"+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

Comment: @seropo please check my ans with output.

Comment: hmm... but still in my app cannot work i try that,running and returning still no value for related_news

Comment: @seropo add your more snippet of code with your question.

Comment: yes thanks but if i use webservice for receipe jsonresponse still cannot but if i use raw json work i checked from server accept application/json

Comment: @seropo Welcome, Happy to help you.

Comment: yes thanks may i ask once again do you know why if i getresponse from webservice cannot detect jsonarray and still returning no value but if i use raw data thats work ?  returning response json is same thanks @RatitalChopda

Comment: please provide me the link of your webservice. to check the json response.

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
JSONArray arr=data.getJSONArray("related_news");
String values=arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
```

has key "id". But string json has not key "id". please changed id to title to check.

Code example

```
 try {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(getResponse());
        String status = result.getString("status");
        String message = result.getString("message");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(status) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray arr = data.getJSONArray("related_news");
            for (int chcek = 0; chcek < arr.length(); chcek++) {
                String values = arr.getJSONObject(chcek).getString("title");
                Log.e("TAG", "welcome: " + values);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("TAG", "error: " + ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use has() method which return true if key exist else false

```
if (status.equals("Success") && message.equals("OK")) {
        Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this, "wellcome" + result.getJSONObject("data").getString("fullname"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray arr = null;
        try {
            arr = data.getJSONArray("related_news");
            String values = arr.getJSONObject(0).has("id") ? arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("id") : "Key not found";
            Toast.makeText(ESNewsDetail.this, "wellcome" + values, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```